# How can Django recognize language changes in a multilingual web page implemented in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, multilingual, django-multilingual

I have already implemented a web page in English using Django. 
I now have a question when I'm trying to create a web page in Chinese. Pages in Chinese will be separated by prefix(/ch/).

I plan to implement a button to change the language, but the question is how Django remembers the changed page. Assuming my domain is 'domain.com', if the language is set to Chinese via the button I would like to have 'domain.com/ch' open when users access 'domain.com'.
However, clicking on a button does not seem to be able to control the urlpatterns of Django(urls.py), and it seems necessary to store the variable corresponding to language in javascript.

I would appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly complex topic, but there's a lot of stuff to help in Django by default. Locale parts of django will look at cookies for language preferences & I believe there is also elements provided by the browser that it can pick up on for a default language to new visitors to a site.

In Django the thing to look out for is [i18n](/questions/tagged/i18n) and the docs on the topic are here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

You need to enable two settings for the best support of multiple languages; [USE_I18N](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-USE_I18N) adds the language element, and [USE_L10N](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#use-l10n) allows for localised formatting of dates, numbers, currency etc.

On the topic of translations, [give this a read](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/) as you need to make sure strings in your python code, javascript & templates that get shown to the user, are wrapped in the appropriate translation function.

In your root `urls.py` file you'll also need to ensure you're using the `i18n_patterns` which will prefix your URLs with the currently enabled language code. An example of it with the Javascript translation URL is;

```
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),
)
```

Once you've got your settings sorted, URLs set to `i18n_patterns` and some `{% trans "" %}` tags in your templates you could test out the actual generation of the message catalogues.

You use two admin commands for this, the first is [makemessages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemessages) then you add the translations to the generated files, and run `compilemessages` to finish the job.